# Update first row entry of a null column of a record

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have a table with columns `UserId`, `Email` and `Mobile`. `Email` has no null values, but `mobile` has nulls scattered in different rows in the table.

I want to update the first row of each null `mobile` with unique `mobile`. I was hoping this would work but not sure.

```
UPDATE       userprofileplus
SET                mobile = 9199225533
WHERE        (UserId IN
                             (SELECT        TOP (1) UserId
                               FROM            userprofileplus AS userprofileplus_1
                               WHERE        (mobile IS NULL) AND (UserId = 5)))
```

My purpose is to prevent users from having unnecessary nulls on the table. One problem I observed is that SQL Server Compact Edition **does not support** the `TOP` keyword. How do I tackle that?

SQL Server CE version is 4.0. I also noticed that `TOP` keyword is perfectly supported by WebMatrix but VS 2010 SP1 denies `TOP` keyword support on SQL Server CE 4. Whats going on here? When run in webmatrix, all the records with null mobile is updated neglecting the TOP criteria.I need just the first returned row to be updated not all. I also tried this. same result

```
UPDATE       userprofileplus
SET                mobile = 9199225533
WHERE        (UserId IN
                             (SELECT        UserId
                               FROM            userprofileplus AS userprofileplus_1
                               WHERE        (mobile IS NULL) AND (UserId = 5) order by userid offset 1 rows))
```

Someone, pls bail me out.

Comment: Can you give us examples of your current rows and your desired output?

Comment: For one, you need `.. WHERE mobilenum IS NULL .....` - it won't work with `isnull` ....

Comment: @marc_s, tnx....I've fixed that above with my actual code which works fine except for the TOP keyword in which sql server CE tags as an unsupported keyword.

Comment: Can you have multiple rows with `UserId = 5` ??

Comment: Also, it seems that SQL Server CE **3.5** and newer should support `TOP` - which version are you using?

Comment: @marc_s, userid is a foreign key on the table.I can have multiple rows with same id.Also my SQL SERVER COMPACT EDITION IS 4.0 (latest version so far).

Comment: @marc....question update notification after several tests above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew!!.......I finally got it after several logical dives.

```
UPDATE       userprofileplus
SET                mobile = 9199225533
WHERE        (mobile is null and userid = 5) and (Id IN
                             (SELECT        TOP (1) Id
                               FROM            userprofileplus AS userprofileplus_1
                               WHERE        (mobile IS NULL) AND (UserId = 5)))
```

I had to use my primary key column as a pivot to ensure a single row is returned from the subquery even though i was using a TOP criteria.
But i'm still curious why VS2010 sqlCE 4.0 does not support the TOP keyword but webmatrix does.Also, whats the reason why all columns where updated even after using the TOP keyword in the other queries?